# Primefaces p:picklist get selected Items in target list

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selection, picklist

I'd like to get the selected elements in my target list of a p:picklist

1: the ajax event="select" gets me only the last selected element, but i need to get all selected elements.

My picklist:

```
<p:pickList
                id="xAttributesPicklist_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}"
                value="#{templateController.model.listAttributesX}"
                var="attributesX" itemValue="#{attributesX}"
                itemLabel="#{attributesX.getName(localeBean.selectedLocale)}"
                showTargetControls="true" showCheckbox="true"
                converter="attributePicklistConverter"
                styleClass="attributesPicklist"
                rendered="#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}">

                <f:facet name="sourceCaption">#{msg.pickListAvailableAttributesX}</f:facet>
                <f:facet name="targetCaption">#{msg.pickListAssignedAttributesX}</f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="select"
                    listener="#{templateController.onPickListXSelect}"
                    update="@([id$=radioAttributeXOrder_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}])" />
                <p:ajax event="unselect"
                    listener="#{templateController.onPickListXUnSelect}" />

                <p:ajax event="reorder"
                    listener="#{templateController.onPickListXReorder}"
                    update="@([id$=radioAttributeXOrder_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}])"
                    oncomplete="setFromDirty();" />

                <p:ajax event="transfer" oncomplete="setFromDirty();" update="@([id$=panelGridReportButtons])" />


                <p:column styleClass="picklistColumnBase">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{attributesX.getName(localeBean.selectedLocale)}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column styleClass="picklistColumnDetail">
                    <h:outputText
                        styleClass="#{attributesX.ascending ? 'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-n' : 'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-s'}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:pickList>
```

The bean method to handle the select event:

```
    public void onPickListXSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    this.model.setSelectedAttributeX((TAttributeX) event.getObject());
    this.model.setAttributesXAscending(this.model.getSelectedAttributeX().isAscending());
}
```

I also have a p:selectOneRadio in my form, which (on change) should modify all selected elements of my targetList in the picklist.

```
<p:selectOneRadio
                id="radioAttributeXOrder_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}"
                value="#{templateController.model.attributesXAscending}"
                layout="grid" columns="1" styleClass="selectRadio"
                rendered="#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}"
                onchange="setFromDirty();">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.btnRadioAscending}" itemValue="true" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.btnRadioDescending}"
                    itemValue="false" />

                <p:ajax event="valueChange"
                    listener="#{templateController.updateAttributesXOrder()}"
                    update="@([id$=xAttributesPicklist_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}])" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
```

My current bean method to handle the changeevent in the p:selectOneRadio:

```
    public void updateAttributesXOrder() {
    if (this.model.getSelectedAttributeX() != null) {
        this.model.getSelectedAttributeX().setAscending(this.model.isAttributesXAscending());
    }
}
```

But it acutally should look something like this:

```
    public void updateAttributesXOrder() {
    if (this.model.getSelectedAttributeXs() != null) {
        for (AttributeX attx : this.model.getSelectedAttributeXs()) {
            attx.setAscending(this.model.isAttributesXAscending());
        }
    }
}
```

What I need is a way to keep track of **ALL** selected elements in my targetList, not only the last one (as I get from the select event).

Problem with filling a list of selected elements (with adding the current selected element in a select event) is, that I never get a unselect event when the user changes the multiselection into a single element selection.

**Update based on reply of Kukeltje:**

added a `<p:ajax onstart>` to my selectOneRadio:

```
<p:selectOneRadio
                id="radioAttributeXOrder_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}"
                value="#{templateController.model.attributesXAscending}"
                layout="grid" columns="1" styleClass="selectRadio"
                rendered="#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}"
                onchange="setFromDirty();">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.btnRadioAscending}" itemValue="true" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg.btnRadioDescending}"
                    itemValue="false" />

                <p:ajax
                    onstart="getSelectedElementsInPicklist('tempalteForm:tabViewProperties:xAttributesPicklist_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}')"
                    event="valueChange"
                    listener="#{templateController.updateAttributesXOrder()}"
                    update="@([id$=xAttributesPicklist_#{!templateController.model.template.transposed}])" />
            </p:selectOneRadio>
```

with the corresponding JS to "find" the selected IDs:

```
        function getSelectedElementsInPicklist(table) {
        var parent = document.getElementById(table)
        var targetListWrapper = parent.childNodes[2];
        var targetListElements = targetListWrapper.childNodes[1]; // ul

        var items = targetListElements.getElementsByTagName("li");

        var ret_obj = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; (i &lt; items.length); ++i) 
        {
            var pickListItem = items[i];
            if (pickListItem.className.indexOf('ui-state-highlight') != -1) 
            {
                ret_obj.push(pickListItem.getAttribute('data-item-value'));
            }
        }

        var resultString = "";

        for (var j = 0; (j &lt; ret_obj.length); ++j)
        {
            resultString = resultString + ret_obj[j] + ", ";
        }

        resultString = resultString.substring(0, resultString.length - 2);

        passToJSFManagedBean ([{name : 'selected_picklist_items', value : resultString}]);

    }
```

I am struggling on how to work with this result the "right way". At the moment i pass the resultString (which represents the selected IDs) to my request map. and calling remotecommand

```
            <p:remoteCommand name="passToJSFManagedBean"
            id="passToJSFManagedBeanCmd"
            action="#{templateController.getParamsFromJS()}" process="@this"></p:remoteCommand>
```

In my Controller I read this on out and get the IDs:

```
    public void getParamsFromJS() {
    String selectedPicklistItems = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("selected_picklist_items");

    String[] picklistIds = selectedPicklistItems.split(", ");

    List<Long> selectedPicklistIds = new ArrayList<Long>();

    for (String s : picklistIds) {
        selectedPicklistIds.add(Long.valueOf(s));
    }

    this.setSelectedItemIdsInPicklist(selectedPicklistIds);
}
```

My problem now is that the listener-method of the ajax event "valueChange" of my selectOneRadio is called **before** the getParamsFromJS() Methode is invoked. So apparently I'm doing something wrong :-)

Help or any suggestions would be great

Thank you.

Comment: PF version? Tried the latest?

Comment: I am currently using primefaces 6.0 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I tried latest trunk to and the events indeed do not pass on modifier keys (shift, ctrl) and when doing a range select with shift, it only sends the last item. There are some things missing in that regard. Question is if you actually need the full list on selecting or on transfer?

Comment: I need the full list on selection

Comment: ok... the only thing I can think of then is to 'onStart' of the ajax event, see if you can get a list of all selected items (or rather their id's) and pass that on as an additional parameter in the ajax call

Comment: @Kukeltje: thanks for your idea: I have updated my question with my (apparently not 100% correct) solution, do you mind have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: check http://leonotepad.blogspot.com/2013/12/primefaces-capturing-target-list-item.html